# Passing a variable to display in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi I'm new to django and there's something I can't figure out. How exactly can I display a variable set in a different file?

choices.py:

```
testvar= 'This is a test variable'
```

views.py

```
from .choices import testvar
```

template.html

```
{{testvar}}
```

Is that it? The import seems to work properly but the string doesn't show.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view has to be something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    testvar = 'value'
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'testvar': testvar})
```

You pass the dictionary that contains your values.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Just like the tutorial explains, you need to pass it as a context entry to the `render()` method of the template object.