# How to use Django template tag within another tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Django website that I'm trying to get internationalized. The image files are all encoded with the language code of two letters. So when a user switches the language, the references to image files are updated with the language code in templates as follows:

```
<img src="{% static 'website/images/contact_us_{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}.png' %}">
```

Problem is, I have to have a tag as well for the path of static content. What is an elegant way to solve this?

Comment: Already discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893356/passing-a-variable-to-display-in-django-template/37893421#37893421  - you have t o pass it from your view and then you can use it

Comment: I had the same problem, you can also check [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574585/django-insert-image-in-a-template-whose-path-is-dynamic) and the associated answers.

Comment: @dmitryro I don't think his problem is about passing data to the view. I think he got this point. His problem is more about using "a template tag in a static tag" (which actually does not seem possible). He should use the |add function according to the answers I got on my similar question (see above for detail)

Comment: You create a custom template tag , load it {% load your_tags %} and use it {% your_tag|code %} and this will solve problems all together https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Problem is resolved thanks to everyone's contribution! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @MarAja suggestion, I followed his/her question and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574585/django-insert-image-in-a-template-whose-path-is-dynamic) which was practically identical to mine. I'm posting what I did, so whoever that lands on this page has a solution. During my research, I did not stumble upon @MarAja's post.

The code is an exact copy, and the choice not to use `add` tag is because according to the Django documentation, it tries to cast the arguments to an int i.e. not intended for strings.

Full code:

```
# Custom Template tag file named "custom_app_tags.py"
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def addstr(s1, s2):
    return str(s1) + str(s2)
```

Finally, usage:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% load custom_app_tags %}

<img src="{% static 'website/images/contact_us_'|addstr:LANGUAGE_CODE|addstr:'.png' %}">
```

Note, I included everything so that whomever gets here later, gets a complete picture of what is going on.